# How to organize external tools in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, customization

This is how one can set them up:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rmcochran/commandpromptinstudiotoolsmenu01152008103357am/commandpromptinstudiotoolsmenu.aspx

My problem is that I have got too many of them set up, and I now need a separate sub-menu or two to keep them organized. I could not figure out how to do that.

Feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the slow and manual way:

1. Select Tools -> Customize
2. Select the Commands tab from the
   dialog
3. Select "Tools" from the dropdown as
   the menu bar to rearrange
4. Click "Add New Menu"
5. Highlight the newly added menu in
   the sample below (called "New Menu")
   and click "Modify Selection" to
   rename the newly created menu item
   if you want to
6. Select "Tools | [your new menu]"
   from the dropdown as the menu bar to
   rearrange
7. Click "add command"
8. Select "Tools" from the categories
   on the left
9. External tools commands are listed
   as commands named "External Command
   x" in the commands list box
   ("External Command 1" until
   "External Command 24" I think)
10. Select the first, Click OK
11. Repeat from 7 until all added.

Tedious, but it will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this through tools->customize.  From here you'll select the commands tab then the rearange commands... button.  In this area you can select the tools menu and organize your external tools by adding sub directories and such.

Answer (score 0):

It was confusing for me when arranging the external commands to toolbar menu. At first I thought that my commands are the ones at the end of list. Later I found that all the configured external tools are shown in the menu (like external command 1 to 7 in my case). So the next external command that I configured was external command 8 and hence forth. Hope this is helpful to some one.